# Using SHA-512 algorithm creates new line char

Tags: java, hash, sha512

I am using "SHA-512" algorithm in Java to create hash with salt. The problem is in hashed string there is always a strange character which brakes line and when I print hashed string it is composed of two lines. But when I use SHA-256 it is shorter and it does not have a new line char.

So why I am getting two line when I use SHA-512?

EDIT: Sorry I did not mention that new line char is in encoded string. So my hashed string is like ".....hvRfXJwYDrnky/uUVzXnxz**\r\n**GFDJ+L3A......" characters "\r\n" causes problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, then you need to set your Base64 line length to something longer. Base64 encoders usually have a max line length after which they add linebreaks.

`sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` is kind of an ugly encoder.  I think you might be able to subclass it and override `bytesPerLine`.  I would use `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`, you can specify the line length in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is in hashed string there is always a strange character

That *suggests* that you're trying to convert the hash (which is binary data) into a string *as if* it were already encoded text, e.g.

```
// This is bad!
String text = new String(hashBytes);
```

A hash *isn't* encoded text - it's just raw binary data. To represent it as a string, you should use something like hex or base64. For base64 conversions, you can use something like [this public domain library](http://iharder.net/base64). For example:

```
// This won't lose data - it's reversible...
String base64 = Base64.encodeBytes(hashBytes);
```

Of course, if this *isn't* what your code is doing, then this answer is useless - but in that case, please post your code into your question.

Comment: sorry I did not mention that I am using BASE64Encoder to encode hashed string. So new line char is in base64 encoded string.

Comment: @KeithRandall: I don't think so - it will lose leading zeroes, and fundamentally it's trying to treat arbitrary binary data as an integer. I would prefer to use a method which was explicitly designed to *just* convert binary to hex.

Comment: @huzeyfe: Ah, then you need to set your `Base64` line length to something longer.  `Base64` encoders usually have a max line length after which they add linebreaks.

Comment: @JonSkeet: true, but you can get those leading zeros back, as we know it is a 64 byte sha-512 output.

Comment: @KeithRandall that makes sense but how can I change line length.. I am using sun.misc.BASE64Encoder?

Comment: @huzeyfe: that's kind of an ugly encoder.  I think you might be able to subclass it and override `bytesPerLine`.  I would use `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`, you can specify the line length in the constructor.

Comment: @huzeyfe: Please show your code. If you're using base64 but getting a "strange character" then you're doing something wrong... the base64 encoder *may* split the data into two lines (it'll be 88 characters, I believe) but that's not the same as a "strange character". I would personally use the base64 library mentioned in my post.

Comment: @Jon Skeet thank you very much for your help. Actually I am using a legacy code and have a limited time. But if I have a time I will change the libraries and keep in mind your suggestion. Thanks very much and really appreciated.

Comment: @huzeyfe: How long do you think it'll take to download a zip file, extract the single Java file you need (it really is *just one file*, plus the docs which of course you don't have to bundle or anything) and use it? I suspect it'll be quicker than working with the existing ugly library.

Comment: @KeithRandall thank you very much. Overriding bytesPerLine solved my issue. Much appreciated. I have limited time and when refactoring I will keep in mind your suggestions. If you create an answer I would like to accept it.

Comment: @Jon Skeet you are absolutely right. I thought I need to add jars etc. If it is one file I can change it tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jon Skeet first thing in the morning was to change library that you suggested ;) It is better now. Thanks again..